# ¿Cómo parsear un array en formato string a array en PHP?

Tags: php, array, parsear

Estoy usando una api para tablas (handsontable) en php drupal 7 y cuando hacemos submit obtengo un array de datos pero en formato string.

```
"[["6396","11","1","2","0","0","1338","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6397","11","2","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6398","11","3","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6399","11","4","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null]]"
```

El problema que tengo es que no encuentro la manera de parsearlo a array correctamente manteniendo las dimensiones. He probado varios métodos pero no funciona correctamente ya que aunque use el método explode con delimitador "," y otras variantes me junta todas las posiciones del array entero como si fuera un array de una dimensión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `json_decode()`. Simplemente suministrale un string con arrays y objetos de JS y este te dará un array.

```
$array = '[["6396","11","1","2","0","0","1338","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6397","11","2","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6398","11","3","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null],["6399","11","4","2","0","0","Break","Break","12-07-1915","00:00",null]]';

var_dump(json_decode($string));
```

**OJO**, a utilizar comillas dobles para definir el string, el array utiliza las comillas dobles dentro, así que haz uso de las simples en PHP.

Comment: Perfecto, he hecho la prueba y ha funcionado correctamente